# Difference between '>' and '-gt'

Tags: shell, test

What's the difference between these:

```
SEC=$(mysql -hxxx -Pxxx -uxxx -pxxx -se "SELECT Seconds FROM tablename")

SEC=100
```

Both return the same result (100). But when I test it with:

```
if [ ${SEC} > 1 ]
then
    echo "SEC GT 1"
else
    echo "SEC LT 1"
fi
```

The first one returns:

```
"SEC GT 1"
```

The second one returns:

```
"SEC LT 1"
```

If however, I change it to:

```
if [ ${SEC} -gt 1 ]
```

then the result is reversed.

I'm assuming it's got something to do with the datatype, and that I presumbaly need to `cast` one or the other to get the same result.

It's just that at present it's messing up my testing, as I have to remember to change the `IF` section every time.

Comment: `>` is string comparison and the `-gt` is arithmetic.

Comment: `if [ ${SEC} > 1 ]` `>` is the file redirection operator in this context. Are you finding a file named "1" after your run this script?

Comment: > is not valid operator for the [\[ command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test); you be thinking of bash's [[.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, while `>` is not a standard `[`/`test` operator, many implementations support it (some as a byte-array comparison operator (`[` builtin of `bash`, `dash` or `mksh`), some as a string comparison operator (`[` builtin of AT&T `ksh` or `yash`)). Of course, it needs to be quoted for the shell not to treat it as the redirection operator.

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222656/38906

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, `[` was implemented as an ordinary command, identical to `test` except that `[` expects an extra argument at the end which must be `]`. (It still exists as an ordinary command, but most shells also have those as built-ins.) Given that it's an ordinary command subject to ordinary parsing, it couldn't use mathematical operators `<` and `>` without quoting: `[ ${SEC} > 1 ]` contains a redirection operator, it's equivalent to `[ ${SEC} ] >1`, redirecting the (empty) output of the `[` command to the file called `1`. The `[` command mostly follows the usual convention of making special options beginning with a dash: most of its operators begin with a dash. So there's `[ -r foo ]` to test whether a file is readable, `[ -r foo -a -w bar ]` to combine two tests with the “and” operator, `[ $x -eq $y ]` to test whether `$x` and `$y` are equal, etc.

These older shells had string equality (the `=` operator, one of the few that deviates from the dash-letter convention) but not string ordering¹. They had numerical comparisons though, e.g. `[ $x -le $y ]` to test whether the integer `$x` is smaller or equal to `$y`, and this set of operators includes numerical equality `[ $x -eq $y ]` where `[ 010 -eq 8 ]` because a leading zero means that the number is in octal.

Ksh introduced the syntax `[[ … ]]`, also available now in bash and zsh. Unlike `[ … ]`, which is an ordinary command, `[[ … ]]` is recognized by the shell's parser, and so special characters such as `(` and `<` can be used inside without quoting (and indeed they must not be quoted). Since `-lt` and friends were already available for numerical comparisons, and `=` was already doing a string comparison, `<` and friends were made string comparison operators (lexicographic order¹). Thus, for example, `[ 9 -lt 10 ]` but `[[ 10 < 9 ]]`.

¹  <sub>String ordering is available with the `expr` utility; it's one of the few uses of `expr` that haven't been subsumed by features of POSIX shells. But beware that `expr` uses the same operator for string and numerical comparisons, so `expr 9 \< 10` but `expr a9 \> a10`.</sub> 
²  <sub>Whether the strings are interpreted as byte strings, or as character strings in the current locale, depends on the shell</sub>

Comment: cheers, that's a great explanation, and very helpful.